# When should you nest model declarations in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

What are the guidelines about when it is better to nest Model name spaces and when it is better to leave them all top-level?

For instance, when I have a few classes that all have something to do with one core class (and the majority of the system only deals with that core class) then my instinct tells me to declare them as such:

```
CoreModel

CoreModel::DependentOne

CoreModel::AnotherDependent
```

Almost always this corresponding to has_many/belongs_to relationships (i'd almost consider this the next candidate for convention over configuration.)

And again, my routes often reflect this nesting:
/CoreModels/:core_model_id/DependentOne/:id

The reason I feel like I should do this is because often two component areas of the same large application may need a supporting component with similar if not identical names as other areas of the software.  I feel like name spacing these dependent models (which only exist to support that core model) is the best way to go.

I'm confused because while some times doing things this way can make stuff easier (such as link_to which needs only to take the DependentOne model and will automatically route correctly) yet other items such as form_for refuse to work properly (because it doesn't route properly and if I add the CoreModel to the form_for it complains about no such route core_model_core_model_dependent_one etc....

Perhaps I haven't been clear enough and so I'll ensure I update this as requests for clarifications come in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`...the majority of the system only deals with that core class...`

In that case, I wouldn't bother namespacing them.

`The reason I feel like I should do this is because often two component areas of the same large application may need a supporting component with similar if not identical names as other areas of the software. I feel like name spacing these dependent models (which only exist to support that core model) is the best way to go.`

Bingo - if you have name conflicts, namespacing is a good way to fix it. But, do you have that problem yet?

Namespacing prevents name conflicts, but in Rails it also introduces some gotchas and headaches and (throughout the app) quite a bit more typing. So, to me, it isn't worth it unless you actually have a name conflict.

Consider a structure like this, with your core model and many that just help it.

```
#Core Models
Model
Supporter
Assister
Helper
Benefactor
```

For most of the life of your app you may never run into a problem. If you do finally hit one, you could just do this:

```
AltModel
AltModel::Supporter    
OtherModel
OtherModel::Benefactor
```

Or if it's really simple just prefixing the class name would work:

```
AltModelSupporter
OtherModelBenefactor
```

For that matter, it's probably simpler to name your core models in this way than it would be to "properly" namespace them:

```
CoreModel
CoreSupporter
CoreAssister
```

So, there are many ways to accomplish what you need, none of which suggest you should bother namespacing the core functionality of your app when you don't actually have a namespace conflict. Given the headaches you've already run into I think you'll be happier leaving the  core models of your app in the top-level namespace and only nesting alternate models that actually have a conflict down the road.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough reply.  It took me a while to digest but I learned a lot.